# JavaScript - parseInt and Number is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple conversion from string (html5 input data) to a integer, but my console log is always returning `Undefined`, is the same result to `Numbers()` or `ParseInt`. If I put a "letter" (do just for test, my form is `input="number"`).

```js
var dia = Number(document.getElementById('dia').value)
var mes = Number(document.getElementById('mes').value)
var ano = Number(document.getElementById('ano').value)

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

  console.log(dia.value)
  console.log(mes.value)
  console.log(ano.value)

  e.preventDefault()

})
```

```html
<form name="form" action="index.html" method="post">
  <div class="">
    <label for="dia">Dia de Nascimento</label>
    <input type="number" name="dia" id="dia">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <label for="mês">Mês de Nascimento</label>
    <input type="text" name="mes" id="mes">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <label for="ano">Ano de Nascimento</label>
    <input type="number" name="ano" id="ano">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
```

Sorry if it's a kind of lame, i found a lot of toppics about this but i just cannot figure out how to solve.

Comment: The issue how you are calling console.log(dia.value), there is not function or property defined for the "dia" you just need to print "dia"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider converting the numbers in the callback method itself.

```
form.addEventListener('submit',  function(e) {
  var dia = Number(document.getElementById('dia').value)
  var mes = Number(document.getElementById('mes').value)
  var ano = Number(document.getElementById('ano').value)
  console.log(dia)
  console.log(mes)
  console.log(ano)

  e.preventDefault()

})
```

Here is a working example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function(){
        form = document.getElementById("form")
        form.addEventListener('submit',  function(e) {
          var dia = Number(document.getElementById('dia').value);
          var mes = Number(document.getElementById('mes').value);
          var ano = Number(document.getElementById('ano').value);
          console.log(dia);
          console.log(mes);
          console.log(ano);
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" action="index.html" method="post" id="form">
      <div class="">
          <label for="dia">Dia de Nascimento</label>
          <input type="number" name="dia" id="dia">
      </div>
      <div class="">
          <label for="mês">Mês de Nascimento</label>
          <input type="text" name="mes"  id="mes">
      </div>
      <div class="">
          <label for="ano">Ano de Nascimento</label>
          <input type="number" name="ano"  id="ano">
      </div>
      <div class="">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve the values inside the addEventListener function. And there is no need to use `.value` on the console since `dia`, `mes` and `ano` are already the values

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

  var dia = Number(document.getElementById('dia').value);
  var mes = Number(document.getElementById('mes').value);
  var ano = Number(document.getElementById('ano').value);

  console.log(dia)
  console.log(mes)
  console.log(ano)

  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<form name="form" action="index.html" method="post">
  <div class="">
    <label for="dia">Dia de Nascimento</label>
    <input type="number" name="dia" id="dia">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <label for="mês">Mês de Nascimento</label>
    <input type="text" name="mes" id="mes">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <label for="ano">Ano de Nascimento</label>
    <input type="number" name="ano" id="ano">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's works! But i don't get why i have to retrieve the values inside the addEventListener. As a public variable, they cannot be accessed in other functions? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can access the the variable because it is global, but the problem there is when you retrieve the values from those input (on document load). There is no values yet. That is why it is giving you undefined

Comment: If you put it on the `addEventListener` function, it will get the **current** value of the input when you click it (which means after the user puts in the value) and show it.

Comment: Hm, i get it. I just was thinking that variable should be updated. Thank you again!

Comment: Happy to help @LucasMaraal

Answer (score 1):

Just change the function like this

```
    form.addEventListener('submit',  function(e) {

        console.log(dia)
        console.log(mes)
        console.log(ano)
        e.preventDefault()

   })
```

Comment: @t.niese here we are taking about the solution not the best practice ...